# Batch File to do something if no new folders made within the last 24 hours?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am now trying to make a batch script that will run everyday and check the folder where all the files are stored. I want to check when the most recent folder (or file within the folder) was created, and if there isn't any new folders (files) in the last 24 hours, then execute this other script that I have working to alert us.

But I do not know how to add before this to create/change a variable IF there is a new folder/file created within the last 24 hours.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:  I have changed my code and I am stuck here. If i remove "set count=" the forfiles line returns the correct number of files modified. But when i set it as set count= it starts to return 0 instead of the correct number.

I also do not know if my IF statement will work yet because I have not gotten that far yet.

```
@echo off
set day=-1
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%day%,now) : d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "result=%%a"
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
set "YYYY=%result:~0,4%"
set "MM=%result:~4,2%"
set "DD=%result:~6,2%"
set "data=%mm%/%dd%/%yyyy%"

set count=forfiles /S /D +%data% /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE echo _" | find /C "_"

IF count = 0 powershell.exe -file C:\User\Project\action.ps1
```

Comment: There is no such command as `IF EXISTS`, so I do not believe that you  fully understand how to do an `IF` statement. In addition to that, if `variable` is supposed to represent a file or directory value stored as a variable, it should be `IF EXIST "%variable%"`, or if delayed expansion is enabled, `IF EXIST "!variable!"`, (if the variable is holding a directory it should also have a trailing backslash, i.e. `IF EXIST "%variable%\"`, or `IF EXIST "!variable!\"`). If it's supposed to be checking if there's a variable named `variable` then it should be `IF DEFINED variable`.

Comment: In order for us to assist you with how to create or change a variable if there is a new folder/file created within the last 24 hours, we need to see that code, the code you've posted is of little use to us without seeing it in the context of the rest of your code. If you don't know how to do it, I can guarantee that there are multiple similar questions on this site for detecting changed file/directory objects within a defined period. I'd suggest therefore that you fully utilise the search facility, _(which is available at the top of each page)_.

Comment: @Compo I have added all of my code.

Comment: @Gerhard Where would i use the %errorlevel%?  Also i have changed the if statement, but setting the variable to the correct count still isnt working so far.

Comment: You said that you knew how to use the `IF` command, just to refresh your memory, _because your new code is also incorrect_, please open a Command Prompt window, type `if /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read its help information.

Comment: If you really want to continue using [[tag:vbscript]] to form your date string, then you could replace lines `3`..`10`, with these two, **1.** `(Echo WScript.Echo CreateObject("System.Text.StringBuilder"^).AppendFormat("{0:MM}/{0:dd}/{0:yyyy}",Now^).ToString(^))>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"`, **2.** `For /F %%G In ('"cscript.exe /Nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"&&Del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs""')Do Set "data=%%G"`.

Comment: run `robocopy . . /S /IS /MAXAGE:1 /L /FP /NS /NC /NDL /NJH /NJS|find ":"&&echo found file modified in 24hrs||echo no files modified in 24hrs` in your current directory

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go, note the for loop to get the count:

```
@echo off
set day=-1
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%day%,now) : d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "result=%%a"
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
set "YYYY=%result:~0,4%"
set "MM=%result:~4,2%"
set "DD=%result:~6,2%"
set "data=%yyyy%/%mm%/%dd%"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('forfiles /S /D +%data% /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE echo _" ^| find /C "_"') do set "count=%%i"

IF %count% equ 0 (
   echo powershell.exe -file C:\User\Project\action.ps1
) else (
   echo count was %count%
)
```

I also changed `set "data=%dd%/%mm%/%yyyy%"` to `set "data=%yyyy%/%mm%/%dd%"` as that is how I recall `forfiles` uses the date format. Not on my windows device, so cannot verify.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a PowerShell script, it might be easier to stick with PowerShell. I have not run this, but it should be close.

```
#Requires -Version 3
if ((Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path 'C:\src\t' |
    Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).AddHours(-24) }).Count -eq 0) {
        C:\User\Project\action.ps1
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) is a string-based language, so this

> ```
> set count=forfiles /S /D +%data% /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE echo _" | find /C "_"
> IF count = 0 powershell.exe -file C:\User\Project\action.ps1
> ```

is nonsense to the parser. What you should be using is a `FOR /F` loop.

---

> I want to check when the most recent folder (or file within the folder) was ***CREATED***, and if there isn't any new folders (files) in the ***LAST 24 HOURS***, then execute this other script that I have working to alert us.

For ***FILES***:

```
robocopy . . /S /IS /MAXAGE:1 /L /FP /NS /NC /NDL /NJH /NJS >nul 2>&1&&powershell -file 'C:\User\Project\action.ps1'
```

Doing this for ***FOLDERS*** will be extremely difficult using native utilities, powershell/vbscript would be easier.